# ¿Cómo obtener (n) palabras de un texto en Java?

Tags: java

Necesito extraer (n) palabras de un texto en Java para Android, de su inicio hasta el número de palabras que se le indique, las palabras están separadas obviamente por espacios:

Pero que tenga en cuenta:

- que elimine los espacios sobrantes del final de la cadena, es decir si acaba con espacio lo elimine
- Para asegurar que se corta bien el texto, si acaba con un signo de puntuación diferente a `.?!` como por ejemplo `& ; : ,` lo sustituya por el punto.

por ejemplo si se decide cortar n palabras y su terminación es `pulvinar &` debe ser `pulvinar.`

**Mi banco de pruebas:**

El array `strI` es la entrada de texto y la `strO` es lo que debería devolver correctamente, si se especifica cortar a 3 palabras.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strI = new String[16];
        String[] strO = new String[16];

        strI[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";
        strO[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";

        strI[1] = "Lorem ipsum dolor, amet.";    
        strO[1] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";

        strI[2] = "Lorem ipsum dolor: amet.";    
        strO[2] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";

        strI[3] = "Lorem ipsum dolor; amet.";    
        strO[3] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";

        strI[4] = "Lorem ipsum dolor! amet.";
        strO[4] = "Lorem ipsum dolor!";

        strI[5] = "Lorem ipsum dolor? amet.";
        strO[5] = "Lorem ipsum dolor?";

        strI[6] = "Lorem ipsum dolor3 amet.";
        strO[6] = "Lorem ipsum dolor3.";

        strI[7] = "Lorem: ipsum & dolor, amet.";
        strO[7] = "Lorem: ipsum.";

        strI[8] = "Lorem: ipsum , dolor, amet.";
        strO[8] = "Lorem: ipsum.";

        strI[9] = "Lorem: ipsum . dolor, amet.";
        strO[9] = "Lorem: ipsum.";

        strI[10] = "Lorem ipsum : dolor, amet.";
        strO[10] = "Lorem ipsum.";

        strI[11] = "Lorem: ipsum ; dolor, amet.";
        strO[11] = "Lorem: ipsum.";

        strI[12] = "Lorem ipsum ? dolor, amet.";
        strO[12] = "Lorem ipsum?";

        strI[13] = "Lorem ipsum ! dolor? amet.";
        strO[13] = "Lorem ipsum!";

        strI[14] = "Lorem ipsum dolor .";
        strO[14] = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";

        strI[15] = "Lorem ipsum";
        strO[15] = "Lorem ipsum.";

        System.out.println(strI[0]);

        for (int i=0; i < strI.length;++i) {

            String outResult = getWords(strI[i],3);
            String flagResult = "F";

            if (outResult.equals(strO[i])) flagResult = "T";

            if (flagResult.equals("T")) {
               System.out.println(flagResult + "[" + outResult + "]");
            } else {
               System.out.println(flagResult + "[" + outResult + "] In/out:" + strI[i] + " =>" + strO[i]);
            }
        }


    }

    public static String getWords(String str, int num) {
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        int total = words.length;
        if (num<0) num = 0;
        if (num>total) num = total;

        String out ="";
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<num-1;++i) {
            out +=  (i==0)? words[i]: " " + words[i];
        }

        //String endChar = words[i].substring(words[i].length() - 1); 

        String endWord = words[i];

        endWord = endWord.replace(".", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(",", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(";", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(":", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace("&", "");

        endWord = endWord.trim() + ".";

        out += " " +  endWord;
        //System.out.println("endChar[" + endChar + "]");
        //comprar la última palabra como termina
        //out += " " + word[i]

        return out.trim();
    }

}
```

**Resultados**
T = true y F = false

```
T[Lorem ipsum dolor.]
T[Lorem ipsum dolor.]
T[Lorem ipsum dolor.]
T[Lorem ipsum dolor.]
F[Lorem ipsum dolor!.]
F[Lorem ipsum dolor?.]
T[Lorem ipsum dolor3.]
F[Lorem: ipsum .]
F[Lorem: ipsum .]
F[Lorem: ipsum .]
F[Lorem ipsum .]
F[Lorem: ipsum .]
F[Lorem ipsum ?.]
F[Lorem ipsum !.]
T[Lorem ipsum dolor.]
T[Lorem ipsum.]
```

Comment: _Necesito extraer (X) palabras de un texto en Java para Android_ ¿las palabras están separadas por espacios unicamente? ¿o incluye simbolos de puntuacion?, ¿puedes agregar algunos ejemplos de la entrada?

Comment: Puedes aclarar un poco tu pregunta? Necesitas obtener las palabras o el numero de ellas? X es un parámetro de entrada?

Comment: me parece que quizo decir, "obtener "n" palabras dentro de un Texto en Java."

Comment: Perdonand, por la mañana con prisas no he podido formular bien la pregunta, @Elenasys si quiero referirme más bien a (n) palabras ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema eran principalmente dos, el primero que se añadía punto final a cualquier sentencia, y no omitías aquellas en las que no se debía poner (como cuando terminaba en ".", "?" o "!".

El segundo problema era que se añadía un espacio siempre antes de "endWord", esto era un problema cuando estaban pro ejemplo "**Lorem ipsum ? dolor, amet.** ya que al separarlas por espacio en cadenas, el símbolo "?" se tomaba como una palabra sola, y antes de añadirla a la cadena final se agregaba un espacio antes. Esto se arregla condicionando que se agregue el espacio solo cuando se tenga más de un caracter. Te dejo el código ya modificado y funcionando (al menos con tus ejemplos)

```
 public static String getWords(String str, int num) {
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------" + words[0]);
        int total = words.length;
        if (num<0) num = 0;
        if (num>total) num = total;

        String out ="";
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<num-1;++i) {
            out +=  (i==0)? words[i]: " " + words[i];
        }

        //String endChar = words[i].substring(words[i].length() - 1); 

        String endWord = words[i];

        endWord = endWord.replace(".", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(",", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(";", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace(":", "");
        endWord = endWord.replace("&", "");

        endWord = endWord.trim();
        /* con este if solo se pone el punto al final si no es alguno de los simbolos que 
         * no se deben reemplazar
         */
        if (!endWord.endsWith(".") && !endWord.endsWith("?") && !endWord.endsWith("!") ) {
            endWord += ".";
        } 
        words[i-1] = words[i-1].trim();
        //solo se añade el esapcio antes del punto si no es un simbolo unico
        if (endWord.length() <= 1) {
            out += endWord;
        } else {
            out += " " +  endWord;
        }

        //System.out.println("endChar[" + endChar + "]");
        //comprar la última palabra como termina
        //out += " " + word[i]

        return out.trim();
    }
```

Comment: Sip perfecto, funciona bien en todos los ejemplos, lo doy por buena, si alguien tiene mejor optimización etc... que exponga su respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Mi propia solución, se puede optimizar usando expresiones regulares...

```
public static String getWords(String str, int num) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    int total = words.length;
    if (num<0) num = 0;
    if (num>total) num = total;

    String out ="";
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<num-1;++i) {
        out +=  (i==0)? words[i]: " " + words[i];
    }

    String endWord = words[i];
    String endChar = endWord.substring(endWord.length() - 1); 

    //System.out.println("endChar[" + endChar + "]");

    if (endChar.equals(".")) endChar = "";
    if (endChar.equals(",")) endChar = "";
    if (endChar.equals(";")) endChar = "";
    if (endChar.equals(":")) endChar = "";
    if (endChar.equals("&")) endChar = "";

    if ((!endChar.equals("?")) && (!endChar.equals("!"))) endChar += ".";

    //System.out.println("endChar[" + endChar + "]");
    endWord = endWord.substring(0,endWord.length() - 1)  + endChar; 
    endWord = endWord.trim();

    String spaces = (endWord.length()>1)? " ":"";
    endWord =  spaces + endWord;
    out += endWord;


    return out.trim();
}
```

Comment: Que bien  se volvío a abrir esta pregunta!

Answer (score 1):

He aquí una solución utilizando expresiones regulares:

```
public static String getWords(String str, int num) {
    String[] array = str.split("\\s+");
    int n = array.length < num ? array.length : num;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(array[i]);
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    result = result.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\\s*[&,.:;]*$", ".");
    result = result.replaceAll("\\s*([?!])$", "$1");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Las palabras son aleatorias?

```
String[] palabras = formatear(palabrasAleatorias(5));
```

Este método obtiene x palabras de un texto.

```
public String[] palabrasAleatorias(int cantidad) {
    final String DELIMITADOR = " ";
    final List<String> palabras = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] todasPalabras = texto.split(DELIMITADOR);

    for(int i=1; i<=cantidad; i++) {
        palabras.add(todasPalabras[Math.floor(Math.random() * todasPalabras.length)];
    }
    return palabras;
}
```

Y este método formatea las palabras obtenidas reemplazando cualquier signo de puntuación que encuentre al final.

```
public String[] formatear(String[] palabras) {
    List<String> signos = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(signos, ",", ";", ":");
    final List<String> formateadas = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String palabra : palabras) {
        palabra = palabra.trim();
        char signo = palabra.charAt(palabra.length() - 1);
        if(signos.contains(String.valueOf(signo))) {
            palabra = palabra.substring(0, palabra.length() - 1) + ".";
            formateadas.add(palabra);
        }
    }
    return formateadas.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

El método `String#trim()` Elimina los espacios a los lados del texto. Luego solo compara si el último caracter del texto existe en la lista `signos`; si es así entonces lo reemplaza con un punto.

Comment: Acabo de añadir más datos a la pregunta, el número de palabras es de inicio del texto hacia n palabras adelante